# Statically linking to macOS framework in CMake

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cmake

I am using a third party macOS framework called `CrashReporter` in my CMake project like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.9" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")

project(bug CXX)

find_package(CrashReporter REQUIRED)

add_executable(bug
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.mm"
)

set_target_properties(bug PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-ObjC")
target_link_libraries(bug PUBLIC "-framework AppKit")

target_link_libraries(bug PRIVATE ${CRASHREPORTER_FRAMEWORK})
```

If I copy my executable to another machine it complains that the library is not found.

**Is it possible to statically link (not embed) the framework in the executable?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A Framework and a static library are two different things. You can't change the nature of a framework to it to be statically linked. BUT! Your third party provider may offer you an installation package that includes a framework, a dynamic library and a static library, so you may have the option to choose the one to link. Or if your third party library is open source you can build it yourself as you prefer. It is even possible that the static and dynamic libraries are shipped inside the framework, because a framework is symply a directory similar to an app bundle. If you installed a package with several flavors, then [you may set this variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK.html) to influence the [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) results:

```
CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK(NEVER)
```

Before `find_package()` so CMake will ignore frameworks and search only for unix libraries.

If you know that there is a static library, and where it is, you may  provide the full name of the static library to the `target_link_libraries()` command:

```
target_link_libraries(bug PRIVATE ${CRASHREPORTER_STATIC_LIBRARY})
```

Assuming that there is a `CRASHREPORTER_STATIC_LIBRARY` variable holding the full name and path of the static library (something like '/path/to/crashreporting.a').